# What is the shrine buff range?

Tags: diablo-iii

How close must party members be to reap shrine effects? Is it based off of in-game yards or "screen" distance (e.g., must be visible on screen)? I never know if party members are close enough to get shrine effects.

Comment: I suspect it is the same as the range in which you get experience for teammates' kills, which is about a screen and a half.

Answer (score 1):

playing on my 1920x1080 23" monitor, I've noticed its a tad more than the area I can see on screen. I've missed shrine pickups just barely out of screen shot, so I know it isn't much farther than my line of sight

Answer (score 0):

The shrine range for your teammates is roughly around 80 (in game) yards.

Comment: Do you have a source for that?